# "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to code a bot that when a user joins the server it adds him the role "Banda canina", I tried to give him an admin role, but it continues giving this error. This is the code

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    let wChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === botConfig.canale_benvenuto);
    if(!wChannel) return console.log('Canale di log non valido');

    let wRole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === botConfig.ruolo_base);
    if(!wRole) return console.log('Impossibile trovare il ruolo base');

    wChannel.send(`${member.user.username}#${member.user.discriminator} è entrato nel server`);
    member.roles.add(wRole);
});
```

I tried the bot in another test server, and it works, but in the main server it doesn't. Here's the complete error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Bot Gio\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:8268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Comment: You said you tried to give the bot admin role, does the admin role actually have administrator powers though? Look inside settings of the admin role and see if `administrator` or whatever it's called is checked. Then click on the channel of `channel.name === botConfig.canale_benvenuto` and see if the bot is there

Comment: I controlled, the admin permissions are checked and the bot is in the channel `channel.name === botConfig.canale_benvenuto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bot should have the permission to manage roles in that server and also be over the role it's giving to new members.

[image: role hierarchy should look like this]

[image: manage roles should be turned on for the bot]

Comment: The problem is that the role already has the permission to menage roles

Comment: is it over the role that you're trying to give them though?

Comment: Just checked, I putted the role of the bot over the user role, thank you